# How to program several sizes of screens in uwp?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

Hi i am Developing a app on universal windows 10 app platform, and when i put some Objects on the XAML window and when change the screen size it's stay how it was before so it's fit the new screen size and if i fix it it's fit the old screen size and i need the app to be universal.

my xaml code:

```
<Page
x:Class="App17.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App17"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Loaded="Grid_Loaded">

    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="Assets/backPHONE.jpg"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="55*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="9*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RelativePanel>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,155,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="128" Width="360" Text="test 123" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontStretch="UltraExpanded" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="26" Tapped="textBlock_Tapped" TextAlignment="Center"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,700,0,-666.8" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="264" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged" Height="32" Grid.Row="1">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="test" IsSelected="True"/>
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="164,675,-2.8,-665" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="test" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Width="120" Grid.Row="1" SelectionHighlightColor="#FFF10000" FontFamily="Century Gothic"  FontSize="12" FontStretch="UltraExpanded" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="White"/>
    </RelativePanel>
</Grid>
```

thanks

Comment: Use a Visual State.  You can define them in a Visual State Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Let me introduce two possible ways to handle various screen sizes related with Universal Windows 10 Apps.

**1. Adaptive Triggers** - you can use them to adjut your layout to different device families - for instance you can define how your Page will look on the smartphone and while app is launched on the PC. Below I tried to add some short instructions how you can start using them.

a) When you have Visual Studio opened, please right click on the MainPage.xaml and select "Design in Blend...":

[image]

b) Go to "States" tab and select icon (marked red rectangle below) called "Add state group":

[image]

c) Now you have to add state, so click the icon next to "Visual State Group" as show below:

[image]

d) Now add two state: "Mobile" and "Desktop" as shown below:

[image]

e) Last step is to set minimum window width to detect when screen size is changed:

[image]

f) Now you are able to set minimum window width for the "Mobile" state:
Please type 320 as below (remember that these are effective pixels not physical)

[image]

Once you click "OK" Visual State for "Mobile" will be configured.
Do the same above steps but for "Desktop" state and type 1024 for minimum window width:

[image]

Now I can switch between two states and adjust the design for each of them:
(Note that currently selected state is marked with red rectange):

[image]

[image]

**1. Device-Family Folders** - you can specify two separate views for Pages but with one code behind. This can help if you have to craft your design specially for mobile devices and for instance fot the PCs.

a) Right click on the project and add new falder called "DeviveFamily-Mobile":

[image]

b) Add new Xaml View called the same like your previous page - in my case this is "MainPage":

[image]

c) Now you have one code behind class but two separate views that will be applied accordingly to device family:

[image]

I hope that it will help you to start. 
You can also watch very good [Channel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2015-Final-Release-Event/Universal-Windows-Platform-Tailored-Experiences?ocid=SessionsInEvent) video or visit [my blog](http://mobileprogrammer.pl) where I am trying to present a lot of helpful samples related with UWP.

Answer (score 0):

you must use AdaptiveTriggers

http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/using-adaptivetrigger-to-build-adaptive-uis-in-windows-10